# how can i validate this simple condition in obj c for my iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, conditional-statements

I am uploading an image file to the FTP, before upload it I need to check weather it is png or jpg, and if not, I should throw a warning alert, I try to do it like this, but it is throwing the alert though its a png of jpg how can I check this condition

```
NSLog(@"%@",filePath.pathExtension);

    if( ![filePath.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"png"] || ![filePath.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"jpg"] || ![filePath.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"PNG"] ||![filePath.pathExtension isEqualToString:@"JPG"] )
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Warning" message:@"Image should be in png or jpg format to upload" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]autorelease];
        [alert show];

    }
```

Comment: what is the output of NSLog?

Comment: what's the problem and what is filePath ?

Comment: This has nothing to do with Xcode.

Comment: what yaar itna simple code diya tha....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should replace `||` with `&&`, otherwise the condition is always true (the extension cannot be equal to `@"png"` and `@"jpg"` simultaneously, which is what's required for the OR-ed condition to evaluate to `false`).

Comment: @downvoter Could you please leave a comment to explain what do you think is wrong with the above answer?

Answer (score 1):

Why you are doing for png,PNG and jpg,JPG, just change its in lowercase latter

```
NSString *str = [filePath.pathExtension lowercaseString];
if (![str isEqualToString:@"png"] && ![str isEqualToString:@"jpg"])
{
    //Your Alert
}
else{
    //Your Task
}
```